# Can't disable driver signing enforcment

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multi-boot

Facts:
Windows 10, dual boot with Kali Linux

Problem: I want to disable driver signing enforcment, the test mode, gpedit hasn't worked, right now I think the best chance to get it working is to get to this screen:

[image: this screen]

I am unable to get to the screen, where you are supposed to press f7. The last thing I am able to is to press restart on the advanced boot options, when it restarts it just goes back to normal.

Comment: Open cmd as administrator and enter `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions true` . It will say the operation completed successfully. Now restart Windows and it will take you straight to the screen shown in your screenshot. You won't need to press F7.

Comment: @n8te thanks, it worked, you can answer this as answer, so I can select it as correct answer and you will get your rep <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open a `cmd` prompt as administrator
- Enter the following command:
  `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions true`
- Now restart Windows and it will take you directly to a screen that looks like this:

[image: Startup Settings]

- Choose option number 7
- When back in Windows you'll want to turn off the option to boot into Advanced Settings so that it doesn't take you straight into that screen every time you boot into Windows.
- Open `cmd` prompt as administrator again and enter:
  `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions false`

Comment: still intresting, why other methods don't work :)

Comment: it might be GRUB, since it visually made it weird, when it came up

Answer (score 0):

[Winaero tweaker](https://winaerotweaker.com/) has a GUI where you can set the computer to always boot to that screen.

To disable driver signature enforcement in Windows, I've had success with [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dse-patcher/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230249)

Comment: What is "this"? Why does it solve the problem? At the very least you should descibe *how* to use the software to solve the problem as asked in the question. [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). How does this tool achieve what is asked? How do you use it? How do you set it up?